# A small form input which upon a submit will display the users name throughout the website

Tags: asp.net, forms, cookies, session-cookies, form-submit

I'm new to coding so please be understanding. I'm after a small form where when the user submits it (it will just be their first name) I can use it throughout the website.

Is it possible to store whatever they input into a Cookie? And then re-call that throughout the website?

I'm using .Net VB. Can someone point me in the right direction of what I should be looking at online for help and guidance.

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: Of course you can store it in a cookie.. database or session! It depends what you will do with that value? what's the application is doing? Check out this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31914/Beginner-s-Guide-To-ASP-NET-Cookies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. The way I prefer: Let's consider it a ASP website and the value is coming from TextBox.

Example:

Register.aspx --> To Get the value.

```
Session["yourSessionVariableName"] = yourTextBoxName.Text;
```

Home.aspx --> To Retrieve the value. (Let's say your are displaying it to a label)

```
yourLabelName.Text = Session["yourSessionVariableName"].ToString();
```

Let me know if it helps. :) 
Happy Coding.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this. This helps. However, how do I go about the onSubmit function. Would it be best to use js to actually store the value and recall it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the value to be stored on onClick / onSubmit event of the button? 

If yes, 

If you're taking a HTML Button Control : Then you have to use JS. 

But if you're  using a ASP Button Control (which I recommend) Control : Then you can write the code on it's onClick event. (In aspx.cs file)